# How do you convert a png to a movie clip and than link it?

Tags: actionscript-3, png, movieclip, animate-cc

I've tried this as many ways as I can figure out. I went to convert to symbol > movie clip, but that doesn't allow me to go into the properties to link anything to where it will have a symbol in the linkage column in my library.

I need to take my png's, turn them into movie clips, and then link them. Does anyone know how to do this? Or if I am doing it right, why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sprite` class, as PNG is not an animation sequence, then use `graphics.BeginBitmapFill()` programmatically. Or, create a new `Sprite` or `MovieClip` descendant class in library, there make a bitmap-filled rectangle and use your PNG as fill pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Animator/Flash. Insert > New Symbol (Check Export for Actionscript and change the class name to whatever you want.. ie: MyImage) Double click MyImage in the library and drag your image into the movieclip on the stage. Now in your actionscript you can create it dynamically. If you already have a movieclip in the library with your image in it right click on it and select properties, then check export for actionscript.

```
var img = new MyImage();
```